# How to start an application at boot time or as a service

Tags: boot, upstart

in order to be able to start my application at boot time i have followed the Upstart instruction.

I have create a file `/etc/init/poolparty.conf`, within which i have defined the following:

```
# poolparty - poolparty job file

# Stanzas
#
# Stanzas control when and how a process is started and stopped
# See a list of stanzas here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#respawn

# When to start the service
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

# Essentially lets upstart know the process will detach itself to the background
expect fork

# Run before process
pre-start script
    [ -d /var/run/poolparty ] || mkdir -p /var/run/poolparty
    echo "starting Poolparty"
end script

# Start the process
exec /opt/poolparty/bin/poolparty start
```

This is an application that needs the network started, the multi-usermode started. In any case, whatever the machine needs to start first need to be there. It can be started at the end of the boot process.

However when i reboot, nothing happens.

What else do i need to do to start it ? Can someone help ?

When i type `service poolparty start`, i either get that the service is already started or nothing. In any case it does not work i checked it.

So if any one could guide me here that would be great. I would like to check the log as well.

Btw `/opt/poolparty/bin/poolparty` is an executable script, that set things and call a java application. It uses jsvc64 to start a java application based on Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying it require network and you are creating new directory so it need local-filesystem also .so you have to use

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
```

or

```
start on (local-filesystem and started networking)
```

instead of

```
start on runlevel [2345]
```

and you can try

```
if [ ! -e /var/run/poolparty ]; then
     /bin/mkdir  /var/run/poolparty
   fi
```

instead of

```
  [ -d /var/run/poolparty ] || mkdir -p /var/run/poolparty
        echo "starting Poolparty"
```

**suggestion :** see upstart log  under `/var/log/upstart` that will help you where you are missing. and also check syntax error of init script using command:

```
init-checkconf -d /etc/init/poolparty.conf
```

and for better understanding of upstart script see [Upstart Ubuntu cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start-on)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The command needs to be run as root does it matter ? (/opt/poolparty/bin/poolparty start)

Comment: i don't think so. most of init script run as root . refer http://askubuntu.com/questions/297992/how-do-i-run-a-script-on-startup-as-superuser

Comment: Yes actually i made it work with " start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)" . Maybe what you try to write that is referred in the doc is "start on started network-services". I could not find in the doc "start on (local-filesystem and started networking)"

Comment: In any case i have no specific requirements at the init of the machine. I just need everything to be up and start the Service.

Comment: I also had to provide a Java_Home, as the service is a java application.

Comment: One last comment i did not need "if [ ! -e /var/run/poolparty ]; then
     /bin/mkdir  /var/run/poolparty
   fi" actually !! I don't really know why an application would need something external to set this folder. In any case it failed at the check. I had a syntax error with it

Comment: i thought you trying to create directory if not exist see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31585484  . it is working . is you problem solve ?